# VSC Pylance disable linting for Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

I am using the Python and Pylance extensions in Visual Studio Code for the benefit of syntax highlighting, auto completion and code suggestions.

Whenever I save a file within the workspace, the linter automatically parses the file and makes corrections where necessary, in my case this also adds a large amount of unrequired new lines around my inline documentation.

Here is a demonstration of the above mentioned behaviour after a file is saved:

[image: gif]

I have attempted to disable the Python Linter for VSC through numerous methods mentioned in other questions to no avail. Whenever I save a file within the workspace, the linter automatically parses the file and makes corrections where necessary, in my case this also adds a large amount of unrequired new lines around my inline documentation.

`settings.json` file:

```json
{
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
    "python.languageServer": "None",
    "python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
        ".vscode/*.py",
    ],
}
```

The Linter setting is disabled within my VSC workspace and user settings:

[image: img]

What I don't understand additionally is that I have disabled `Lint On Save` though this behaviour still persists:

[image: img]

I have confirmed this is definitely behaviour coming from the Pylance/Python extensions, when I disable them the issue goes away.

Comment: Is it normal to have docstrings outside of a function? I thought generally they were nested within it.

Comment: That is more of a personal preference coming from other languages, I dislike putting them within the function specifically for Python; this is one of the reasons I want to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the setting `editor.formatOnSave` in VSC does this globally for all languages and seems to have resolved automatic formatting.

[image]